# Trying to update mysql database form in php

Tags: php, mysql

My database manages to retrieve values when I navigate from the previous page.
When I click the 'Update Product' button, the line

## Update product

appears. What I want is when I click the 'Update Product' button, and have modified a record beforehand, I would hope to update the database with the values as well and a confirmation message is displayed to confirm this.

Code:

```
<form id="updateForm" name="updateForm" action="<?php echo "?mode=update&ID=" . $productDetails["ID"]; ?>" method="post">                                
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductCostPrice">ID</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductCostPrice" name="ID" type="text" readonly 
                               value="<?php echo $productDetails["ID"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductName">Film Name</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductName" name="FilmName" type="text" 
                                value="<?php echo $productDetails["FilmName"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductDescription">Producer</label>
                        <input id="Producer" name="productDescription" type="text" 
                                value="<?php echo $productDetails["Producer"]; ?>">                
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductPrice">Year Published</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductPrice" name="YearPublished" type="text" 
                               value="<?php echo $productDetails["YearPublished"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductStock">Stock:</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductStock" name="Stock" type="text" 
                               value="<?php echo $productDetails["Stock"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductEan">Price:(&#163)</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductEan" name="Price" type="text" 
                               value="<?php echo $productDetails["Price"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input id="updateSubmit" name="updateSubmit" value="Update product" type="submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

PHP:

```
if (((!empty($_GET["mode"])) && (!empty($_GET["ID"]))) && ($_GET["mode"] == "update")) {
               echo "<h1>Update product</h1>";
                if (isset($_POST["updateSubmit"])) {
                    if ((!empty($_POST["ID"])) && (!empty($_POST["FilmName"])) 
                            && (!empty($_POST["Producer"])) && (!empty($_POST["YearPublished"])) 
                            && (!empty($_POST["Stock"])) && (!empty($_POST["Price"]))) {
                        $query = "UPDATE ProductManagement "
                                . "SET FilmName = '" . $_POST["FilmName"] . "', "
                                . "Producer = '" . $_POST["Producer"] . "', "
                                . "YearPublished = '" . $_POST["YearPublished"] . "', "
                                . "Stock = " . $_POST["Stock"] . ", "
                                . "Price = '" . $_POST["Price"] . "' "
                                . "WHERE ID=" . $_GET['ID'] . ";";
                        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                        if ($result == false) {
                            echo "<p>Updating failed.</p>";
                        } else{
                            echo "<p>Updated</p>";
                                }
                                                                                        }
                                                    }
        }
```

So I need the database to update what new value I have entered and it once the 'Update product' Button is pressed, the original value appears and the value is not updated on the database. Why is this? I don't get any error messages.  Thanks

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: Have updated question

Comment: what output are you getting i.e. Updating failed or updated ???

Comment: You should update your question yet another time because "it won't do this" is also not sufficient. What is happening? Do you get an error, or, is the update operation not executed at all? Did you debug to check the values of the variables you use in the conditions like $_POST["updateSubmit"] ?

Comment: Is easy to get an error in all that query concatenation.Echo it out and edit your question,also post the connection.I`m not going to say anything about sql injection )

Comment: You dont have a `$_POST["Producer"]` use `$_POST["productDescription"]`

Comment: you shouldn't put your db query like that in the middle of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you dont POST the ID but you GET the ID value. input boxes with the `readonly` attribute don't post values.

change:

```
if ((!empty($_POST["ID"])) && (!empty($_POST["FilmName"]))
```

to:

```
if ((!empty($_GET["ID"])) && (!empty($_POST["FilmName"]))
```

**Edit:** Total changes to make to make this work:

HTML:

```
<form id="updateForm" name="updateForm" action="<?php echo "?mode=update&ID=" . $productDetails["ID"]; ?>" method="post">                                
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductID">ID</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductID" name="ID" type="text" readonly 
                               value="<?php echo $productDetails["ID"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductName">Film Name</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductName" name="FilmName" type="text" 
                                value="<?php echo $productDetails["FilmName"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductProducer">Producer</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductProducer" name="Producer" type="text" 
                                value="<?php echo $productDetails["Producer"]; ?>">                
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductYearPublished">Year Published</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductYearPublished" name="YearPublished" type="text" 
                               value="<?php echo $productDetails["YearPublished"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductStock">Stock:</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductStock" name="Stock" type="text" 
                               value="<?php echo $productDetails["Stock"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="updateFormProductPrice">Price:(&#163)</label>
                        <input id="updateFormProductPrice" name="Price" type="text" 
                               value="<?php echo $productDetails["Price"]; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input id="updateSubmit" name="updateSubmit" value="Update product" type="submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

PHP:

```
if (((!empty($_GET["mode"])) && (!empty($_GET["ID"]))) && ($_GET["mode"] == "update")) {
               echo "<h1>Update product</h1>";
                if (isset($_POST["updateSubmit"])) {
                    if ((!empty($_GET["ID"])) && (!empty($_POST["FilmName"])) 
                            && (!empty($_POST["Producer"])) && (!empty($_POST["YearPublished"])) 
                            && (!empty($_POST["Stock"])) && (!empty($_POST["Price"]))) {
                        $query = "UPDATE ProductManagement "
                                . "SET FilmName = '" . $_POST["FilmName"] . "', "
                                . "Producer = '" . $_POST["Producer"] . "', "
                                . "YearPublished = '" . $_POST["YearPublished"] . "', "
                                . "Stock = " . $_POST["Stock"] . ", "
                                . "Price = '" . $_POST["Price"] . "' "
                                . "WHERE ID=" . $_GET['ID'] . ";";
                        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                        if ($result == false) {
                            echo "<p>Updating failed.</p>";
                        } else{
                            echo "<p>Updated</p>";
                                }
                                                                                        }
                                                    }
        }
```

Comment: And after this @Mihai is right about the post producer thing in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `name` and `id` of your *input* fields to the same respective values. I see you call id from one and name from another input field in your php and it might be causing the function to fail.

Like so for example:

```
<label for="ID">ID</label>
<input id="ID" name="ID" type="text" readonly value="<?php echo $productDetails["ID"]; ?>">
```

you should be fine using `$_POST[]`, since the method of your form is `POST`. (If you change it to GET it will put all the values in the url)